# How to install postfix with MySQL 5.1 in CentOS 5.3

Tags: mysql, centos, postfix

All rpms for postfix is built for MySQL 5.0, however I have MySQL 5.1 installed on my server, how do I proceed installing postfix for MySQL 5.1 with the MySQL support?

Comment: postfix build with the mysql 5.0 libs should be able to talk to a mysql 5.1 server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existing one in CentosPlus repository should work, it's dependency is on:

```
libmysqlclient.so.15  
libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15)
```

However if it doesn't work, then grab the source existing RPM:

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.5/centosplus/SRPMS/

Make sure the following are installed on your system ("yum install FOO" as root) as well as the "rpm-build" package :

```
$ cat postfix.spec | grep BuildRequires
BuildRequires: gawk, perl, sed, ed, db4-devel, pkgconfig, zlib-devel
BuildRequires: setup >= 2.5.36-1
BuildRequires: openldap >= 2.0.27, openldap-devel >= 2.0.27
BuildRequires: cyrus-sasl >= 2.1.10, cyrus-sasl-devel >= 2.1.10
BuildRequires: pcre, pcre-devel
BuildRequires: mysql, mysql-devel
BuildRequires: postgresql, postgresql-libs, postgresql-devel
BuildRequires: openssl-devel >= 0.9.6
```

Run these commands as your normal user to set up basic RPM building:

```
cd ~/
mkdir -p redhat/{BUILD,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}
mkdir -p redhat/RPMS/{athlon,i386,i486,i586,i668,x86_64,noarch}
echo -e "%_topdir $HOME/redhat\n%packager root <root@localhost>" > ~/.rpmmacros
```

Place your downloaded SRPM from above into ~/redhat/SRPMS/, then:

```
rpmbuild -ba postfix-2.3.3-2.1.centos.mysql_pgsql.src.rpm
```

...to create a compatible package for the MySQL 5.1 RPMs you have installed that you know is built against them.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to rebuild Postfix. Just install the Mysql 5.1 shared-compat package of the same version of your Mysql 5.1 server. That'll provide the libmysql Centos 5.x expects.